# Why does adding an index to one of the two keys used to join two tables make the execution time slower than not using any index at all?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I am executing queries where two tables *authors* and *work_authors* are being joined. I am using MySQL. *authors* and *work_authors* have a one-to-many relationship and *authors* contains around 7 million records and *work_authors* contains around 21 million records.

```
SELECT  t2.author_id, t1.work_id, t2.name 
FROM    work_author AS t1, 
        authors AS t2 
WHERE   t1.author_id = t2.id AND
        t2.name LIKE '%Tolkien%';
```

Firstly, there is no index at all in the database, i.e. no primary key or other indexes. Then the query on average takes 24 seconds on my machine. When adding index i.e. making the id-column of *authors* primary key, but not any index or primary key for the *work_author* table, the query takes on average 64 seconds on my machine.

Secondly, when I add an non-unique index to column *author_id* the *work_author* table the query on average takes 4 seconds on my machine.

How can this be the case? Why is the query taking longer when adding index to one of the attributes used to join than having no index at all? And then when adding index to the both join keys it executes faster than the other two alternatives. Anyone who can explain this?

Comment: Index usage effectiveness depends on table statistic. If rows amount which matches the condition is over approx. 5-7% then table scan is in general more effective than index usage.

Comment: Try to create index `authors (name, id)`. Or covering index `authors (name, id, author_id)`. Also test `authors (id, name)` and `authors (id, name, author_id)`.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Tip 2: t1 and t2 are poor table aliases. Chose something that makes sense, like `wa` for `work_author`, and `a` for `authors`.

Comment: @Akina, could you elaborate a bit on your first comment? What do you mean "by rows amount which matches the condition is over approx. 5-7%"?

Comment: This is a practical observation. The whole topic is quite extensive. See [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  Optimization  /  Optimization and Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimization-indexes.html) and [The Optimizer Cost Model](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cost-model.html)

Comment: @Akina - Where does the 5-7% come from; my experience is "about 20%".

Comment: @RickJames Different data - different relation. From my practice - the cases when table scan is slower at 10% are too rare. You observe another statistic - this is a norma. Only practice is a criteria - in each separate case.

Comment: Yeah.  My 20% is observing a cutoff -- If an index filters the number of rows down to less than 20%, then the index will be used; else the Optimizer will choose to do a table scan.  That cutoff is imperfect, but the Optimizer needs a rule to make the decision.  (Actually, there is a "cost-based algorithm", but in many cases, the _effect_ is a cutoff at about 20%.)

Answer (score 1):

No index can help `LIKE '%Tolkien%'`.  However, ...

Consider adding a `FULLTEXT` index to `authors.name` and using

```
MATCH(name) AGAINST('+Tolkein' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This will run a lot faster.

`PRIMARY KEYs` are important.

Using InnoDB is important.

Do use the `JOIN...ON` syntax instead of commajoin.

A many-to-many table is optimized by having two indexes as discussed here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table